# How to resolve undefined image file in NuxtJS

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

So I am getting image and passing it to my Nuxt Js app by putting my api inside `.env` file outside Nuxtjs folder.

I am then passing it like this

```
 computed: {
    featuredImage(){
    
      return this.$config.myPublicVariable + 'storage/'
    }
  }
```

Then like this in my html

```
<img :src='featuredImage+ front.featured_image' :alt="front.title" />
```

If i do not have any image i get `undefined:1 GET http://localhost/storage/img/profile/undefined 404`

How do i resolve this to a default image so that i do not get that error??

Also i added the code inside

```
methods: {
    featuredImage(){
    
      return this.$config.myPublicVariable + 'storage/'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this:

```bash
php artisan storage:link
```

and keep in mind, that after running that command, there will be symlink created. so all of the paths will look like this:
http://localhost/img/profile/image.png

Also ill suggest to think a bit different approach: If there is non null value for this property - `front.featured_image` you use it as part of request, if there is null value - then you fetch a default picture from Backend.

P.S: Storage prefix will be gone.

More to read : [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)